# Copy Text from Input form into DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create 1 input field and one Div. 
When u write text in the Input and hit the button i want the text to be displayed in the DIV. Its so simple but it just won't work.. i hope someone can do this easy task for me.
I tried last:

```
<form>
        Bearbeitungstext: <input id="textInput" type="text"><br>
        <input type="button" value="text einbinden" onclick="$('texxxt').val($('#textInput').val())">
</form>

    <div id="texxxt">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `id selector` properly,

```
$('#texxxt').text($('#textInput').val());
```

Also you have to use `.text()` instead of `.val()`, `.val()` is not a function for `div` elements. It is for form elements which are having `value` property.

And the best approach for your case would be binding an explicit event handler,

```
var div = $("#texxxt"),inp = $("#textInput");
$("form button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  div.text(inp.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with php `$_GET($whatever);` also, to do this you will need the `name="whatever"` on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bearbeitungstext:
        <input id="textInput" type="text"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="text einbinden" onclick="$('#texxxt').html($('#textInput').val())"/>
        <div id="texxxt">
```

to change DIV content we use html() not val()